# Not able to Collapse/Expand the View in Appbarlayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am using Appbarlayout followed by cordinatorlayout with a RecyclerView to just collapse/expand a simple TextView. But still don't know whats I am doing wrong there. The TextView(textViewMainTop) still not collapsing/expanding .Not able to findout the issue. Please have a look on my 
xml code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <!--  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.5" > -->

             <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="3.5"> 

            <com.openskylabs.skymo.components.TypefacedTextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMainTop"
                style="@style/custom_roboto_midium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bubbled_textview"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:text="Good evening, Eric"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llFirstFavTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_fev_small" />

                <com.openskylabs.skymo.components.TypefacedTextView
                    style="@style/custom_roboto_midium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:text="Set Fav" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewVertical"
                android:layout_width="0.5sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#60000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llSecondInviteTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_cont_small" />

                <com.openskylabs.skymo.components.TypefacedTextView
                    style="@style/custom_roboto_midium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                    android:text="Invite" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewBelowRay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1sp"
            android:background="#60000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#eaeaea"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvOrderList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Here I want to collapse the first part. In in second part I am using RecyclerView.

Comment: What is the exact issue ? Post screenshot.

Comment: what kind of performance issue you are facing please elaborate the problem more.

Comment: @jaydroider I just want to collapse/expand the  TextView (textViewMainTop) ..So I put it in Appbarlayout ..But unfortunately its not collapsing.

Comment: Please Check this it may help you http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/android-tip-custom-coordinatorlayout.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `AppBarLayout` to collapse the widgets you want. Your `Text View` goes inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

> Like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: Try removing the LinearLayout.  Should be CoordinatorLayout -> AppBarLayout -> CollapsingToolbarLayout -> TypefacedTextView

Comment: @ayvazj I need all LinearLayouts to handle some layout weights. But also its not working after commenting all linearlayouts as well.

Comment: @RanjitPati Collapse should work in above scenario. Show me the current behavior of your screen.